# Importar dados do Informix para o MySQL

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com base nos dados de um ERP. Este ERP usa o banco INFORMIX cujo padrão de exportação de arquivos é DELIMITADO POR PIPES E SEM QUALIFICAÇÃO DE TEXTO.

Quero criar uma query no INFORMIX e importa-la automaticamente par a a minha aplicação, que usa o banco MySQL, periodicamente.

Criei um arquivo php para realizar esta tarefa o qual vou acioná-lo via crontab. Porém não estou conseguindo importar o arquivo. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
require_once("libraries/BD.class.php");
BD::conn();

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ctplano.txt'
INTO TABLE ctplano
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(id_plano, nroplano, contared, contadep, contades, descrconta, natureza, resultado, pedecgccpf, pedeccusto, ctafluxo, diario, ativo);
```

Mas está retornando a mensagem

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'DATA' (T_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\kurma\imports\import.php on line 6

Comment: Seu código (php) é só isso? não falta aspas aí? enviar o insert/load para o banco?

Comment: Você não colocou uma query em um string, e não executou ela, esse código não faz nada, coloque a query que carrega o arquivo em uma váriavel, execute ela com a extensão mysqli ou classe PDO, a sintaxe está correta, só falta executar da forma certa.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Poderia me dar um exemplo prático por favor?